# The cdf of a continuous random variable is uniform: where do we use continuity?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, continuity, random-variables

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable with cdf $F_X$ strictly monotone (increasing).  Let $Y:=F_X(X)$. Then $Y\sim U([0,1])$.

The proof is

$$
F_Y(y):=P(Y\leq y):=P(F_X(X)\leq y )\overbrace{=}^{F^{-1}_X \text{well defined}}P(F^{-1}(F_X(X))\leq F^{-1}_X(y))=P(X\leq F^{-1}_X(y))\underbrace{:=}_{Q_X \text{ quantile function}}P(X\leq Q_X(y)):=F_X(Q_X(y))=y
$$

Notice $F^{-1}_X$ is well defined because $F_X$ is continuous (as $X$ is continuous) and strictly monotone.

---

I want to generalise the proof to the case in which $F_X$ is not strictly monotone increasing but simply monotone increasing. My attempt is

$$
F_Y(y):=P(Y\leq y)\overbrace{:=}^{\text{let } y:=F_X(x)}P(F_X(X)\leq F_X(x))=P(X\in \{\tilde{x}\in \mathbb{R} \text{ s.t. } F_X(\tilde{x})\leq F_X(x))\})\overbrace{=}^{F_X \text{ monotone}} P(X\in \{\tilde{x}\in \mathbb{R} \text{ s.t. } \tilde{x}\leq x\})=P(X\leq x):=F_X(x):=y
$$

---

Question: Where do I use continuity of $X$ in the proof above?

Comment: You write "let $y:=F_X(x)$. How do you know there exists $x$ such that $F_X(x)=y$? This does not hold if $X$ is discrete. So that is where you have used continuity of $X$.

Comment: Continuity of the distribution ensures that there are no point masses, so the CDF $F_X$ has no jumps. If $F_X$ had a jump, then there would be some interval $I=(y_1,y_2)\subset[0,1]$ such that there is no $x$ with $F_X(x)\in I$.

Comment: Technically you only used continuity of $F_X$ not (absolute) continuity of $X$. But you definitely used continuity of $F_X$, to ensure that the image of $F_X$ contains $(0,1)$.

Comment: Why do we have $$\{\tilde{x}\in \mathbb{R} \text{ s.t. } F_X(\tilde{x})\leq F_X(x))\})=  \{\tilde{x}\in \mathbb{R} \text{ s.t. } \tilde{x}\leq x\}$$ or even $$P(X\in \{\tilde{x}\in \mathbb{R} \text{ s.t. } F_X(\tilde{x})\leq F_X(x))\})=P(X\in \{\tilde{x}\in \mathbb{R} \text{ s.t. } \tilde{x}\leq x\})\ ?$$