# Whats wrong in my method for finding probability distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, functions, random-variables

Consider $X$ to be a continuous random variable with distribution function $$F(x)=Pr[X\leq x]$$
Write down the distribution followed by random variable F(X).

**My approach**

$$Pr[F(X)\leq x]= Pr[X\leq F^{-1}(x)]=F(F^{-1}(x))=x$$
The answer given is uniform distribution on [0,1]. Can somebody explain where did i go wrong?

Comment: Although distributions are increasing functions, they are not necessarily injective, thus $F^{-1}(x)$ could be a set with more than one element.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1999095/the-cdf-of-a-continuous-random-variable-is-uniform-where-do-we-use-continuity